# Lambda timeout after 10s both in serverless offline and online

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lambda, timeout, serverless

I am new to lambda, mongodb and nodejs and I'm trying to access a mongodb database follwoing this tutorial: [pretty nice tutorial][1] . This is my second attempt at connecting to mongodb and after spending hours setting things up I run into an unsurmountable wall and none of all the answers on stack overflow have helped. *Any help will be greatly appreciated.*

I have inserted console.log instructions and they both are executed so the timout happens after connecting to the database, but after that I don't know what is executed. **I have also set up VPC properly in AWS Lambda so I have no idea why this is timing out.** *( See edit below)* It might be worth mentioning that I have never been able to get past this stage: of all the things I have tried there is always a timeout error.

I have a handler.js file which, among other functions, has this one:

```
    'use strict';
    require('dotenv').config({ path: './variables.env' });
    const connectToDatabase = require('./db');
    const Note = require('./models/Note');

    module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
      context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
      console.log("here1");

      connectToDatabase()
        .then(() => {
          Note.create(JSON.parse(event.body))
            .then(note => callback(null, {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: JSON.stringify(note)
            }))
            .catch(err => callback(null, {
              statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
              body: 'Could not create the note.'
            }));
        });

        console.log("here2");
    };
```

I also have a db.js file and a Note.js file as instructed in the tutorial ( here posted respectively )

```
//file db.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let isConnected;

module.exports = connectToDatabase = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('=> using existing database connection');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  console.log('=> using new database connection');
  return mongoose.connect(process.env.DB)
    .then(db => { 
      isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
    });
};

//file Note.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const NoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  title: String,
  description: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', NoteSchema);
```

Both serverless offline and serverless online give me a timeout error:

Serverless offline:

```
here1
=> using new database connection
here2
✖ Lambda timeout.
```

Serverless online:

```
START RequestId: f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b Version: $LATEST
2022-10-25T11:53:44.171Z    f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b    INFO    here1
2022-10-25T11:53:44.171Z    f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b    INFO    => using new database connection
2022-10-25T11:53:44.311Z    f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b    INFO    here2
END RequestId: f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b
REPORT RequestId: f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b  Duration: 10013.48 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 100 MB Init Duration: 864.37 ms    
2022-10-25T11:53:54.174Z f75c6e23-84e2-485c-8fb4-065a95bbbb9b Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

I am sending this JSON POST request through Insomnia:

```
{ 
    "title":"some title",
    "description": "some description" 
}
```

After changing the timeout time to 5 mins, I am getting an error related to the connection to mongo saying I should whitelist my IP. It is whitelisted but I will investigate.
[1]: https://medium.com/hackernoon/building-a-serverless-rest-api-with-node-js-and-mongodb-2e0ed0638f47

Comment: If you have resolved part of your problem please do not add an answer to that part to the question. Instead delete that part from the question. You can move it into a separate question and self-answer it.